# How to fetch() multiple resources?

Tags: javascript, html, json, promise, fetch

I have a list of addresses pointing to json resources. I want to download those files to be able to use them in later processing.

I have this piece of code that uses the fetch() method:

```js
let urlList = [
         "https://url.to/resource1.json",
         "https://url.to/resource2.json"
       ];
  let promiseList = [];
  let jsonBaseList = [];

  urlList.forEach (function (url, i) {
    promiseList.push (
      fetch(url).then (function (res) {
        jsonBaseList[i] = res.json();
      })
    );
  });

  Promise
    .all(promiseList)
    .then (function () {
      console.log('All done.');
    })

console.log('jsonBaseList: ', jsonBaseList)
```

Thus, the `jsonBaseList` contains a list of `promises`.

**But I just want a list of json objects instead.**

It's possible?

Comment: You miss a step `fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data=> jsonBaseList[i] = data);`

Comment: Side note: *But I just want a list of json objects instead."* JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return that `res.json()` and use the resolved value in the next `.then`, since `Response.json()` returns another promise.

```js
let urlList = [
         "https://url.to/resource1.json",
         "https://url.to/resource2.json"
       ];
  let promiseList = [];
  let jsonBaseList = [];

  urlList.forEach (function (url, i) {
    promiseList.push (
      fetch(url).then (function (res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function (res) {
        jsonBaseList[i] = res;
      })
    );
  });

  Promise
    .all(promiseList)
    .then (function () {
      console.log('All done.');
    })

console.log('jsonBaseList: ', jsonBaseList)
```

**Update:** I just edited your current code in order to make it work. But you can write it better:

```js
let urlList = [
  "https://url.to/resource1.json",
  "https://url.to/resource2.json"
];

let jsonBaseList = [];

const promiseList = urlList.map((url) => {
  return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
})

Promise.all(promiseList).then(values => {
  jsonBaseList = values;
  console.log('All done.');
})

console.log('jsonBaseList: ', jsonBaseList)
```

**Update:** The `console.log` at the end of the code will output an empty array since promises are run asynchronously after the current script is run. So you can:

- Put it inside `.then`
- or put it in a chained `.then`
- or use the `async/await` syntax (a cleaner way to write promises)

```js
(async function() {
  let urlList = [
    "https://url.to/resource1.json",
    "https://url.to/resource2.json"
  ];

  const promiseList = urlList.map((url) => {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
  })

  const jsonBaseList = await Promise.all(promiseList)
  console.log('All done.');
  console.log('jsonBaseList: ', jsonBaseList)
})()
```

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov - Agreed. Although pooria, you probably want to remove the `console.log` at the end or at least explain why it will always log `[]`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, the `jsonBaseList` contains a list of promises.

Yes, because `res.json()` returns a promise. But as of when you show your `console.log`, `jsonBaseList` will be `[]` because that code runs before any of the promises settle.

The minimal change to your code for `jsonBaseList` to have values in it in code run after the promises settle is:

```
// ...
// ...
let urlList = [
    "https://url.to/resource1.json",
    "https://url.to/resource2.json"
];
let promiseList = [];
let jsonBaseList = [];

urlList.forEach (function (url, i) {
    promiseList.push (
        fetch(url) .then (function (res) {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then (function (value) {     // ***
            jsonBaseList[i] = value;  // *** This is what I added
        })                            // ***
    );
});

Promise
    .all(promiseList)
    .then (function () {
        console.log('All done.');     // *** Use `jsonBaseList` here
    })

// Removed the `console.log` here that would have logged `[]`
```

**but** it can be much simpler; all of the above can be replaced with:

```
let urlList = [
    "https://url.to/resource1.json",
    "https://url.to/resource2.json"
];
Promise.all(urlList.map(url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json())))
.then(jsonBaseList => {
    // ...use `jsonBaseList` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here...
});
```

Notice that you use `jsonBaseList` in the `then` handler on `Promise.all`. I don't declare it in a broader scope because it's not filled in until that handler is called (that's the reason your `console.log` at the end will always log `[]`). If you declare it in a broader scope, you make it likely you'll try to use it before it's available (as in the question's code).

But if want it in a broader scope and you realize it won't be filled in until later, add:

```
let jsonBaseList = []; // *** Not filled in until the promises settle!
```

and then change

```
.then(jsonBaseList => {
    // ...use `jsonBaseList` here...
})
```

to

```
.then(list => {
    jsonBaseList = list;
})
```

(Or use `const` and `jsonBaseList.push(...list)`.)

---

Side note: You probably want to handle the possibility that the HTTP request failed (even though the network request succeeded — this is a footgun in the `fetch` API I write about [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), it doesn't rject on HTTP failure, just network failure). So:

```
let urlList = [
    "https://url.to/resource1.json",
    "https://url.to/resource2.json"
];
Promise.all(
    urlList.map(
        url => fetch(url).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
    )
)
.then(jsonBaseList => {
    // ...use `jsonBaseList` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here...
});
```

Comment: I think we need to stick with the question itself, not teaching extra stuff since we don't know the level of the questioner. We can just mention a link to that extra information as a piece of advice.

Comment: @pooria - I'm not sure what you're referring to. The above is primarily a very direct answer to the actual question.

Comment: @mplungjan - ...but I've tried to clarify anyway. :-D

Comment: @mplungjan - The `jsonBaseList` array is the fulfillment value of the promise from `Promise.all`. My suggested replacement doesn't fill in the array piecemeal, it delivers the complete, filled array to the fulfillment handler. When you do `Promise.all([a, b, c])`, the fulfillment value of `Promise.all`'s promise is the fulfillment values of `a`, `b`, and `c` (in that same order).

Comment: Yes, I see now. `jsonBaseList ` is now just a  named variable in the "outer" `then` from the `Promise.all` - that was what was confusing compared to the previous script

Comment: @mplungjan - Well, not *anonymous* (it has a name, `jsonBaseList`). It's just that it's a parameter now rather than a variable (though the distinction btw them in JavaScript is very minor :-) ).

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for your promises to be done first

```
await Promise.all(promiseList)
console.log('jsonBaseList: ', jsonBaseList)
```

Comment: If the OP can use `await`, the code can and should be completely restructured. *(edit: **not** my downvote)*

Comment: It doesn't resolve the issue. By using await you may avoid using of `then` but the issue persists, because the reason is that author doesn't use the `res.json()` method properly. See the correct answer made by @pooria